# TWA shows address bar but assetlink is correct

Tags: android, apk, keystore, trusted-web-activity

I have a bubblewrap generated app-release-bundle.apk and my assetslinks are correct.

My assetlinks are correct because I ran `keytool -printcert -jarfile app-release-signed.apk` and I copied the sha256 value into the .well-known/assetslinks.json. The [tool from google](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator) confirms it is correct.

But none the less when I install the apk file the adress bar is there. I have not uploaded anything to google play yet so I know I have the right keystore.

Does anyone know anything else to try? Is there a way to see the error that is generated in the apk when it can not confirm the assetlinks.json?

Comment: I also tried Peters Digital Asset Link tool at it looks exactly the same as the file I can reach on my domain.

Comment: I actually have multiple assetlinks in my assetslinks.json. One for another app as well. This app works fine. So I know the file can be reached.

Answer (score 0):

I was just about to do

```
> adb logcat -v brief | grep -e OriginVerifier -e digital_asset_links
```

from the [Google article](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/android-for-web-devs/#troubleshooting) to debug the problem. But then it just randomly started working. I guess you just need to wait a couple hours.